# New temporarily variables in a frequently called method

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, garbage

Would it more efficient to **not** assign new temporarily variables in a method that is called very frequently? (> 1000x s)

So a current example. I'm assigning 3 new integer values, instead passing these values directly to another method.

```
// What I'm currently doing
public virtual byte GetByte(Vector3 worldPos) {
    worldPos -= transform.position;
    int x = Mathf.FloorToInt(worldPos.x);
    int y = Mathf.FloorToInt(worldPos.y);
    int z = Mathf.FloorToInt(worldPos.z);
    return GetByte(x, y, z);
}
```

But would it be more efficient to pass these values direct, instead of assigning 3 new variables?

```
// would this be more efficient?
public virtual byte GetByte(Vector3 worldPos) {
    worldPos -= transform.position;
    return GetByte(
        Mathf.FloorToInt(worldPos.x),
        Mathf.FloorToInt(worldPos.y),
        Mathf.FloorToInt(worldPos.z));
}
```

Comment: You already have both versions, try them and log the difference, you'll see exactly how both behave in your environment. Also you tagged this "garbage", are you talking about memory efficiency? (Which you can also log yourself)

Comment: Define "more efficient". Do you mean faster? [If you have two horses and you want to know which of the two is the faster then race your horses. Don’t write short descriptions of the horses, post them on the Internet, and ask random strangers to guess which is faster!](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do result in different IL being generated.

Current (using int x = Mathf.FloorToInt(worldPos.x);...):

```
.method public hidebysig newslot virtual instance uint8 GetByte1 (
        valuetype ConsoleApplication5.Vector3 worldPos
    ) cil managed 
{
    .locals init (
        [0] int32 x,
        [1] int32 y,
        [2] int32 z
    )

    IL_0000: ldarga.s worldPos
    IL_0002: ldfld int32 ConsoleApplication5.Vector3::x
    IL_0007: call int32 ConsoleApplication5.Mathf::FloorToInt(int32)
    IL_000c: stloc.0
    IL_000d: ldarga.s worldPos
    IL_000f: ldfld int32 ConsoleApplication5.Vector3::y
    IL_0014: call int32 ConsoleApplication5.Mathf::FloorToInt(int32)
    IL_0019: stloc.1
    IL_001a: ldarga.s worldPos
    IL_001c: ldfld int32 ConsoleApplication5.Vector3::z
    IL_0021: call int32 ConsoleApplication5.Mathf::FloorToInt(int32)
    IL_0026: stloc.2
    IL_0027: ldarg.0
    IL_0028: ldloc.0
    IL_0029: ldloc.1
    IL_002a: ldloc.2
    IL_002b: call instance uint8 ConsoleApplication5.X::GetByte(int32,  int32,  int32)
    IL_0030: ret
}
```

Alternative:

```
.method public hidebysig newslot virtual instance uint8 GetByte2 (
        valuetype ConsoleApplication5.Vector3 worldPos
    ) cil managed 
{
    IL_0000: ldarg.0
    IL_0001: ldarga.s worldPos
    IL_0003: ldfld int32 ConsoleApplication5.Vector3::x
    IL_0008: call int32 ConsoleApplication5.Mathf::FloorToInt(int32)
    IL_000d: ldarga.s worldPos
    IL_000f: ldfld int32 ConsoleApplication5.Vector3::y
    IL_0014: call int32 ConsoleApplication5.Mathf::FloorToInt(int32)
    IL_0019: ldarga.s worldPos
    IL_001b: ldfld int32 ConsoleApplication5.Vector3::z
    IL_0020: call int32 ConsoleApplication5.Mathf::FloorToInt(int32)
    IL_0025: call instance uint8 ConsoleApplication5.X::GetByte(int32,  int32,  int32)
    IL_002a: ret
}
```

In theory, the alternative *could* be more efficient as it doesn't incur the cost of storing and retrieving the int values from the local variables so there are less instructions needed to execute the method. However, the code MSIL will still be JITted at runtime and may end up the same depending on how it is optimised.

I would stick with the current version as it makes debugging easier as you can see the result of the `FloorToInt` calls by inspecting the variable.

The only way to know for sure is to benchmark the code, odds are though that this is a rather pointless "optimisation", there are probably much better ways to speed up your application!

Comment: Bizarre. Do they still show up so different when compiled in release mode?

Answer (score 5):

It makes no difference. Local variables are added to the stack. And values that are used as function parameters are also added to the stack. So in both cases, the same things are added to the stack.

So just use whatever you think is more readable.

Comment: that's not entirely accurate if you look at the MSIL, in the version without local variables, `x`, `y` and `z` stay on the execution stack whereas in the version with local variables they are stored and then retrieved from the local variables

Comment: @TrevorPilley Yes, but that’s a difference you won’t be able to notice, and in this case, compilers may decide to optimize that too.

Comment: Why do registers always get left out? It is entirely possible the JIT compiler will choose to store locals in CPU registers instead of storing them on the stack.

Comment: @mikez That’s true, but doesn’t that still apply to both cases?

Comment: Sure it does. I think you've got the essence of the answer. Some kind of temporary storage needs to be used in both cases. Whether you give that storage location a name like "x" or "y" is immaterial. Looking at the MSIL is misleading since what really matters is the machine code generated by the JIT.

Comment: @mikez Agreed. That and what such a line / such a command actually means in terms of performance. An extraneous local variable is unlikely to be the source of bad performance ever. That’s beyond micro optimization.